# API consuming problem either API documentation is not a complete or i do not understand it to implement

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins

```html
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\n\t\"registrationNumber\": \"AA19AAA\"\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-api-key: REPLACE WITH YOUR API KEY",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>

json format

{
  "registrationNumber": "WN67DSO",
  "taxStatus": "Untaxed",
  "taxDueDate": "2017-12-25",
  "artEndDate": "2007-12-25",
  "motStatus": "No details held by DVLA",
  "motExpiryDate": "2008-12-25",
  "make": "ROVER",
  "monthOfFirstDvlaRegistration": "2011-11",
  "monthOfFirstRegistration": "2012-12",
  "yearOfManufacture": 2004,
  "engineCapacity": 1796,
  "co2Emissions": 0,
  "fuelType": "PETROL",
  "markedForExport": true,
  "colour": "Blue",
  "typeApproval": "N1",
  "wheelplan": "NON STANDARD",
  "revenueWeight": 1640,
  "realDrivingEmissions": "1",
  "dateOfLastV5CIssued": "2016-12-25",
  "euroStatus": "Euro 5"
}
```

Now I got the code but i want to know the Object.value like in previous
example and the previus example json format was not like the current json format
$make  = $data['VehicleDetails']['Make'];
$model = $data['VehicleDetails']['Model'];

Comment: example of registration number WN67DSO

Comment: the previous api url look like this when submit the registration http://qwikcarbuyer.com/car-data/?q=WN67DSO&submit=Submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
function reg_form()
{
    $form = "
            <form method='GET' action='http://qwikcarbuyer.com/car-data'>
              <input type='text' name='q'>
              <input style='width:100%;margin-top:3px;' type='submit' name='submit'>
            </form>
              ";

    return $form;
}

add_shortcode('get_reg_form', 'reg_form');

function get_vehicle_api()
{



$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  
   => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\n\t\"registrationNumber\": \"AA19AAA\"\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-api-key: REPLACE WITH YOUR API KEY",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

actually my previous json format was Nested JSON Objects that is why i was not able to implement.